# Erro no include ao subir o site

Tags: php, servidor, include

Olá! Vou ser breve. Estou com problemas no servidor 000webhost.com. Subir meu site teste para verificar como ficaria no ar o  login no facebook. O erro é esse:

> Warning:
>   include(/storage/ssd2/781/3154781/public_html/lib/Facebook/autoload.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /storage/ssd2/781/3154781/public_html/users/loginFace.php on line 6
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening
>   '/storage/ssd2/781/3154781/public_html/lib/Facebook/autoload.php' for
>   inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in
>   /storage/ssd2/781/3154781/public_html/users/loginFace.php on line 6
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Facebook\Facebook' not found in
>   /storage/ssd2/781/3154781/public_html/users/loginFace.php:10 Stack
>   trace: #0 /storage/ssd2/781/3154781/public_html/index.php(2):
>   include_once() #1 {main} thrown in
>   /storage/ssd2/781/3154781/public_html/users/loginFace.php on line 10

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Parte do código onde acontece o erro:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)) { 
   session_start(); 
}

include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/lib/Facebook/autoload.php');
/*require('../lib/Facebook/autoload.php');*/

unset($_SESSION['face_access_token']);
$fb  =  new  \Facebook\Facebook([ 
'app_id' => '1511055948960318' ,
 'app_secret' => '710b34a0395d103abdbfe8909878e82e' ,
  'default_graph_version ' => ' v2.9 ' , 
  // ' Default_access_token '=>' {access-token} ', // opcional
]);
```

O código no servidor Wamp funciona perfeitamente. Todas as pastas e subpastas estão certas. Alguém poderia me ajudar? Obrigado!

Comment: E na pasta `/storage/ssd2/781/3154781/public_html/users/loginFace.php` existe o arquivo??

Comment: sim, se tarata do código acima onde está o erro. loginFace.php

Comment: Não é o que a mensagem de erro está dizendo, você conferiu se não há nenhuma diferença de case nas letras? Ex: longinface.php ou Users

Answer (score 1):

Se você estiver utilizando a conta free desiste, esse Hosting e cheio de regras não configuráveis, que eles deixam default por segurança.

Erros inexplicáveis acabam acontecendo funciona perfeitamente em outra lugar e nele não funciona e você acaba perdendo horas tentando matar um erro que não existe, utilizo esse hosting só pra pequenos scripts de teste

Nesse seu erro fala que o caminho está errado ou o arquivo não encontrado
verifique as Permissões talvez ajude